# Decreased CSS Specificity with new HTML5 elements

Tags: css, html, css-specificity

Earlier to apply styles to a sidebar we would write the following

```
<div id="sidebar">
<p>Some text...</p>
</div>
```

and the corresponding CSS to set the color to Red would be like

```
#sidebar p{
color: Red;
}
```

The **CSS Specificity here is {0,1,0,1}**

In HTML5 We have the aside element that could be used as

```
<aside>
<p>Some text..</p>
</aside>
```

and the CSS to set the color to Red would be

```
aside p{
color:Red;
}
```

By using the HTML5  element the **CSS Specificity is {0,0,0,2}**

Using **HTML5 elements improve the semantics**. But **HTML5 elements reduce the CSS Specificity**. Provided that the target browsers support all HTML5 elements which among the 2 approaches would be appropriate?

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from having `<aside id="sidebar">` and rules targeting `aside#sidebar`, but whether you should target ids at all is a matter of debate with some.

Comment: Depend if your targeting HTHML5 only or not. I don't think your question can be answered... or the answer is simply use which will support the target html. Maybe you could explain why you don't think what you are suggesting is correct....seems you are pointing out the facts rather than a question?

Comment: "Provided that the target browsers support all HTML5 elements" you wouldn't have written legacy markup to begin with, and you wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: If the change in specificity does not affect your program--in a well designed application it hopefully would not--then what is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Provided that the target browsers support all HTML5 elements which among the 2 approaches would be appropriate?

The latter approach using HTML5 elements would be the best approach, however there are two things to consider regarding rule specificity:

1. HTML5 is better at reducing clashes based on just element name alone as there are more of them, and when used correctly. Consider:

   ```
   <div class="section">words...<div class="aside"><p>an aside</p>
   ```

   versus

   ```
   <section>words...<aside><p>an aside</p>
   ```

   The latter is better as the semantics of the document are within the tags themselves.
2. When you are reusing a structure, its fine to add `id` and `class` attributes to make structure clearer.

   ```
   <section>words...<aside><p>an aside</p>
   <section>copyright...<aside><p>year of copyright</p>
   ```

   versus

   ```
   <section class="article">words...<aside><p>an aside</p>
   <section class="copyright">copyright...<aside><p>year of copyright</p>
   ```

   Here, the class on the latter adds context and reduces rule ambiguity.

So ultimately the answer to your question is use HTML5 elements intelligently with classes where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN doc

> The specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS
>   declaration based on the count of each selector type. In the case of
>   specificity equality, the latest declaration found in the CSS is
>   applied to the element. Specificity only applies when the same element
>   is targeted. CSS rules that directly target an element will always
>   take precedence over rules that an element inherits from an ancestor.

Then the tag, is lower then class, lower then id, 
Also are evaluated External css link file precedence, and inner /in line css declaration.

For this kind of information you can refer to specific browser (engine)

for Mozilla you can refer to this doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

In your case you have a id css rule (more spcecific) and a tag css rule (minor specific)

Comment: The OP knows about specificity. He's asking a concrete question--does the change in specificity caused by using new semantic elements instead of classes affect his decision to use them or not?